# In a multi-level one-to-many relationship, is it appropriate for the lowest entity to record all IDs in the upper layer?

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

Top level - company

```sql
create table company(
  id unsigned tinyint not null auto_increment,
  parent_id unsigned tinyint,
)
```

Next level - department

```sql
create table department(
  id unsigned smallint not null auto_increment,
  company_id unsigned tinyint not null
)
```

Next level - group

```sql
create table group(
  id unsigned mediumint not null auto_increment,
  department_id unsigned smallint not null
)
```

Bottom level - employee

```sql
create table employee(
  id unsigned int not null auto_increment,
  group_id unsigned mediumint not null
)
```

If the employee only records the group information he is in, then when I query the department information he is in, I need to connect 2 tables.

If I want to check his company information, I need to connect 3 tables.

If I want to look up the top company of the subsidiary he is in, then N+3 tables are needed.

In this case, is it permissible for this employee to record the group ID, department ID, and direct subsidiary ID he is in?